# Using a scope from a related model in another scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two related models such as this:

```
class PartCategory < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :part_types 
  scope :engine, where(:name => 'Engine') 
end 

class PartType < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :part_category 
end
```

I would like to add a scope to the PartType model such as:

```
scope :engine_parts, lambda { joins(:part_category).engine }
```

But when I try that, I get the following error:

NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class

I don't have a lot of experience with the scope thing, so I am probably missing something fundamental here. Can someone please tell me what it is.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :engine_parts, lambda { joins(:part_category).merge(PartCategory.engine) }
```

Basically, the result of `joins(:part_category)` is the join of two models, so you can't call `.engine` on it directly, you need to compose scopes in this manner.

See [Here for more](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge#note_content-1272)

Comment: Using `&` is deprecated.  Use `merge()` instead.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660867/why-using-merge-method-with-scopes-isnt-working-anymore-on-rails-3-1) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/66003f596452aba927312c4218dfc8d408166d54)

Comment: `ActiveRecord#merge` doc is here:  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge